# Для чего нужно возвращаемое значение в перегрузки операторов?

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, return

Всем привет!
Не могу никак разобраться с перегрузкой операторов в C++.

Есть некоторый код, который я хочу привести в пример, его я добыл на одном из ресурсов, где объяснялась тема перегрузки операторов:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
        int var;
        MyClass() { }
        MyClass(int a)
        : var(a) { }

        MyClass operator+(MyClass &obj) {
            MyClass res;
            res.var= this->var+obj.var;
            return res; 
        }
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj1(12), obj2(55);
    MyClass res = obj1+obj2;

    cout << res.var;
}
```

В данном коде, по моей точке зрения, происходит следующее:

Строка MyClass obj1(12), obj(55); инициализирует объекты obj1 и obj2, а так же по порядку передаёт значения 12 и 55 в член класса var(a), тем самым присваивая члену var эти значения для каждого отдельного объекта.

Далее, Строка MyClass res = obj1+obj2; выполняет сразу несколько операций, первой выполняется часть obj1+obj2;, которая передаётся в данную часть кода:

```
MyClass operator+(MyClass &obj) {
            MyClass res;
            res.var= this->var+obj.var;
            return res; 
        }
};
```

И вот именно в этой части кода я начинаю задаваться вопросом, а зачем нам возвращаемое значение return res;?
По моей логике, мы здесь перегружаем оператор + и записываем результат в член класса var, с помощью записи res.var. Если это не так, то поправьте меня.
Дальше у меня начинают появляться ещё вопросы. Зачем мы возвращаем return res;? Что находится в res, результат выполнения операции сложения? Просто, если он передаёт результат операции сложения, то разве не логичнее сделать возвращаемое значение таким return res.var? Я пробовал такую запись и результат был таким же. Однако, на этом я не остановился и решил вовсе убрать возвращаемое значение из данного блока кода. Когда я его убрал, результат на мое удивление тоже не поменялся! Почему результат все равно вывелся таким же? А когда я решил написать return 0;, то вывелся 0. Хотя 0 это же совершенно другой тип данных? Во первых, как он вообще передался, ведь там тип данных MyClass должен быть, а во вторых, почему вывелся 0, если при удалении return, результат вывода не менялся?

Comment: С места "вообще убрал возвращаемое значение" подробнее — как, после этого программа скомпилировалась? Может, она не скомпилировалась, и запустился старый скомпилированный вариант?... И, кстати, `const` не забывайте — вы же не собираетесь изменять слагаемое? Ну, а чтобы понять, зачем возвращаемое значение... Ответьте себе на вопрос — а зачем вам вообще оператор сложения? Или, например, при сложении двух чисел — к чему вообще их результат?...

Comment: Проблема просто в том, что я не понимаю как работает данный код. Я и сам не знаю для чего там возвращаемое значение. Тема вопроса как раз в том, что я не понимаю как оно работает.

Comment: если вы высыпаете из одной коробки 12 апельсинов, а из второй коробки 25 апельсинов. то *суммарно* вы высыпали "37" или "37 апельсинов" ?

Comment: Я понимаю к чему вы клоните) Просто если посмотреть в участок блока main(), то там ещё есть запись MyClass res = obj1+obj2;. Я ведь правильно понимаю, что первым делом сначала обрабатывается участок кода obj1+obj2 с помощью перегрузки, а только потом результат возвращается в MyClass res = (результат), и он уже передаётся в конструктор, где есть член класса var(результат)? Если это так, то почему возвращаемое значение из перегрузки является res, а не res.var? Просто для меня res в блоке перегрузки это просто пустой объект в который можно что то положить, только если дать ему допустим тот же var

Answer (score 2):

Сама идея перегрузки операторов в том, чтобы можно было писать то же `a+b` не только для чисел, но и для объектов пользовательских классов.

Поскольку идея выполнять для `a+b` что-то типа "записать a в файл b" или что еще, никак не напоминающее умножение, хотя и вполне реализуема, но ужасна сама по себе, операторы в идеале должны иметь ту же семантику, что и встроенные.

В вашем классе есть одно поле — число `var`, так что логично применять оператор для сложения этих `var`. Можно, конечно, и для умножения или деления, но это будет уже неверная семантика. Так что будем складывать.

Но для чего? Вы же не пишете в программах `2+15` и все? Результат сложения чему-то присваивается. Поэтому он должен быть. Иначе в таком присваивании никакого смысла!

Можно, конечно, возвращать, например, строку... но это опять же нарушение семантики :)

Давайте просто возвращать такой же объект. Потому что можно вернуть и число, но как-то странно смотрится

```
MyClass a, b;
int с = a + b;
```

Нет?

Итак, возвращаем такой же объект. У которого член `var` является суммой членов.

Очевидно, что слагаемые не изменяются, правда ведь? Так что объявить оператор мы должны как

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass &obj) const
```

или как свободный оператор

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass &obj1, const MyClass &obj2)
```

Собственно, дальше только написать суммирование. Я бы, кстати, написал как

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass &obj) const
{
    return MyClass(var + obj.var);
}
```

Вот вкратце и все.

Когда вы возвращаете число, тот же 0, у вас просто из этого нуля создается объект возвращаемого типа `MyClass`. Конечно, вполне можно и так. Просто подробная запись через `MyClass` понятнее. Вы не запутаетесь, что именно она возвращает.

Примерно так... Если что непонятно и теперь — спрашивайте.

Comment: Мне в целом понятно что вы написали) Просто мне не понятно почему в данном участке кода res.var= this->var+obj.var;
            return res;  присваивание идёт к res.var, а потом возвращается просто res? В чем был смысл присваивать к члену класса результат, а возвращать в итоге лишь объект res? Мне именно этот момент не понятен

Comment: Потому что создан объект `res`, который и возвращается. И что значит "возвращать лишь объект"? Вот как раз если бы возвращать `var`, могло бы быть недоумение — почему возвращается не весь объект, а лишь его поле? Откровенно говоря, мне непонятно, что вам непонятно...

Comment: Ну в блоке перегрузки оператора, res же является объектом класса MyClass? Если мы пишем res.var = и присваиваем в него какое-то значение, то это значение по логике и должно передаваться с помощью return res.var. А если мы пишем return res, то как по мне это не логично, ведь res это просто объект, с помощью которого можно достучаться до поля var, в котором, по идее, как я думаю и должен лежать результат сложения двух объектов или я не прав?

Comment: Harry, иногда нужно другими делами тоже заниматься. Ты постоянно тут...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Просто общения не хватает. Особенно сейчас, когда всё и все на удаленке...

Comment: У вас телега перед лошадью. Не член как какая-то часть единого целого, а объект как всего лишь вспомогательная оболочка для члена... Снаружи вообще не должно быть никакого доступа к членам-данным, кроме как через функции-члены. Словом, мне кажется, что вы саму парадигму классов не очень хорошо чувствуете. С другой стороны, "понять — значит привыкнуть", так что просто используйте как есть. Только учтите, что плясать надо от класса, а не от того, что там у него внутри.

Answer (score 0):

В общем покопавшись немного в интернете, я смог наконец ответить на свой вопрос.

Объект res, созданный внутри перегруженного оператора +, возвращается функцией

```
return res;
```

Далее, объект res, созданный в функции main(), принимает все свойства возвращаемого объекта, включая значение поля var (происходит **копирование объекта**).

Теперь, когда объект res в функции main() содержит все свойства объекта res из перегруженного оператора +, можно обратиться к полю var этого объекта, чтобы получить результат сложения

```
cout << res.var;
```

В данной теме меня волновал момент в коде, где происходил сам факт передачи объекта из класса в блок main().

Для меня, как для человека окунувшимся в ООП, было не понятно, каким образом целый объект присваивается другому объекту. Но теперь узнав, что все свойства одного объекта, могут заменять свойства другого (в данном случае по средством копирования объекта в другой объект), данная тема для меня закрыта =)

Comment: По факту, здесь ничего сложного нет, просто я зациклился на моменте, когда один объект, который был вообще в другой локальной зоне, вдруг взял и стал использоваться в блоке main()